# Cocos2d : CGRect Expands with Sprite when running CCScaleBy

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How do you make the CGrect for a sprite expand with a sprite as it is running CCScaleBy. For me, the CGrect just stays in it's original position while the sprite expands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the boundingBox cgrect. It should have all transformations of the sprite.
CGRect r = [sprite boundingBox];